# What does the "@" symbol mean in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I came across this code written in TCL:

```
set GSID(featureSetDesc)       @$GSID(descPath)/featDesc
```

But I can't seem to find what the "@" symbol stands for in TCL.. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commercial at symbol (`@`) doesn't mean anything special at all to Tcl. It's a normal non-letter non-whitespace character. (It *does* mean things to Tk in certain places such as when [specifying a classic X11 bitmap that comes from a file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetBitmap.htm#M6) for things like cursors or icons, but that's a pretty esoteric use these days.)

Well, there's one exception and that's channel redirections in [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm#M11). But that's not what you've got this case.

Comment: OK got it, I thought it was part of the syntax, but now it seems just some trick the previous guy was playing. Thanks!

Comment: Another exception is a symbolic name for a C procedure in [\[incr Tcl\]](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ItclLib/RegisterC.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Assume the value of the variable GSID(descPath) equals "/home/me"

Then the value of GSID(featureSetDesc) will equal "@/home/me/featDesc"